# ¿Error al realizar Deploy a Heroku?

Tags: java, linux, git, heroku, deployment

Estoy realizando el despliegue de un aplicativo realizado en Java a un servidor nube en heroku. Deposite la app en el repositorio Git local de mi maquina y al intentar realizar el push para subir el código al servidor aparece lo siguiente:

```
$ git push heroku master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/egarcia/.ssh/id_rsa':

 !  Invalid path.
 !  Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name.
 !
 !  SSH Key Fingerprint: 6e:3b:77:cc:bc:58:60:d9:05:96:fe:1c:89:3d:78:48

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Alguna Idea sobre el mensaje de error?
gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te está pidiendo que creas llaves ssh. Es muy raro que tengas que hacerlo. Intenta creando esas llaves ssh. Puede que despues te deje hacer deploy de tu código.

Los datos que te pedirá seran la ruta(trae una por defecto asi que puedes darle enter o escribir una ruta distinta que es lo que te recomiendo) y lo siguiente es opcional(pero te recomiendo que la pongas), te pedirá que le coloques una contraseña y luego que la confirmes.

Comment: Así es, era un inconveniente con la clave ssh, volví a realizar todo el procedimiento y funcionó perfecto